# What types of vulnerabilities just can't be located by a default scanner?

Tags: web-application, vulnerability-scanners

If I'm wiling to test a web application.

For what types of vulnerabilities can't a application scanner scan and where can't a application scanner scan (eg. in what property) by its most "forces"?

Scanners such as Vega, Nikto, Burp.

Comment: That's going to be up to the scanner. Each scanner scans different things

Comment: Anything the scanner was not programmed to scan for. The problem is that a negative result doesn't imply that no vulnerability is present - just that the scanner did not find it.

Answer (score 4):

Automated scanners, especially with out-of-the-box configuration, can only identify low hanging fruits at best. What types of attack vectors are covered, depends on the individual tool.

This leaves a broad range of attack vectors that are not covered, which will most likely fall into one of the following categories:

- Business Logic Vulnerabilities

  Security Scanner do not understand your business logic. A typical example is a web-shop that allows an attacker to manipulate the price during checkout. A scanner cannot know that changing this specific value results in a loss for the company selling the product.

---

- Multi-Stage Vulnerabilities

  Some vulnerabilities need several distinct steps before they can actual trigger. If you must perform multiple steps to get the application in the right state to exploit a specific vulnerability, the automated scanner will very likely miss it. Complex authentication and authorization protocols like [OAuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) and [OpenID Connect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID_Connect) fall into this category as well. Exploiting those often requires several complex steps.

---

- Compliance Violations

  Security problems are not always purely technical in nature but can also be compliance driven. Lets take a vulnerability that allows a user to see [PII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_data) of other users by circumventing a search filter. An automated scanner cannot identify the nature of the data and also doesn't know that access to this data is a violation to the [GDPR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Data_Protection_Regulation).

---

- Violations against security design principles

  There are security risks that are not immediately exploitable, but leave open the potential for attacks once the stars align. They often stem from neglected security design principles. This could be the violation of the principle of least privilege. Users that have more permissions than required might not be able to compromise the application right away, but under the right circumstances (e.g. a 0-day in an API that shouldn't be accessible with proper defined access restrictions) this negligence leads to an actual security problem. A scanner cannot foresee such scenarios or even identify violated security principles.

---

- Vulnerabilities that need access to the source code or configuration

  Many security scanners use a black box approach. They do not know the source code or the configuration of the system. There is a broad range of vulnerabilities that can easily be missed without this internal information and are therefore also easily missed be a security scanner.

This list is not necessarily comprehensive. The main message is that there are a lot of issues that cannot be detected automatically at the moment. Relying on a security scanner to verify application security is therefore not sufficient for most applications.

Answer (score 1):

Here're some common difficult challenges to application security automatic scanners that they usually fail to detect or they could have false positive detections:

- Hidden paramater detection for further scanning
- Hidden or relatively referenced URL detection for further scanning
- Business/logic security impact to identify a vulnerability from potential false positive detections. Threat with CSRF attacks belongs to this kind of challenge. Scanners also have problems with the vulnerabilities only shown when a specific value of a parameter is set.